# Aggregating rows in Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

Is there a way to combine, sum and rename rows in a report using Business objects Webi without going to the universe? I'm really new to Webi reports.

Consider this:
|Event|NumberOfattendees|
|-|-|
|DanceA|100|
|DanceAA|100|
|MemberD|100|
|MemberDD|100|

Expected output:

| Event | NumberOfattendees |
| --- | --- |
| CDanceAAAA | 200 |
| CMemberDDDD | 200 |

Thank you!!!

Comment: did you find the solution? maybe you can try to use case when statement

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to combine row results then you can use New Variable in Webi Reports.
Other way is adding a BREAK on that column with a specific condition and then use Sum on 2nd column to consolidate the results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start of with "it depends".
If you know how you want to group them, then you can create a new dimension variable to support them.

For example, you could create a variable called Event Group like:
=IF(Left([Event];5)="Dance";"Dance";If(Left([Event];6)="Member";"Member");"Other")

Or you could create a spreadsheet with an Event to Event Group mapping, load that as a new data provider, merge the two data providers on Event and then use your new Group Mapping from the Excel provider in your report.